# Send post request data on codeigniter with special values

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, rest, frameworks

im writing a codeigniter application and im trying to implement my own commenting system

### The system

I want to make a `POST` request on my `API` page with the comment body, the username from the guy who made it and the location on the comment (see below)

### Sending the data

Sending the data is pretty easy with codeigniter. The REST server library will handle the `POST` request and will make sure that is not spam.

The code im using for the form:

```
<?= form_open(base_url().'api/newcomment'); ?>
    <?php
      $form_properties = array(
                         'name' => 'comment',
                         'size' => 100,
                         'id' => 'comment'
                    );
    ?>
    <p><?= form_label('New comment', 'comment'); ?></p>
    <?= form_input($form_properties); ?>
    <p><?= form_submit('', 'Post'); ?></p>
    <?= form_close(); ?>
```

It's not a normal form since im using codeigniter's form library in order to render them!

### The actual problem

In my view (Codeigniter is using the `MVC` style) i can access the username as a simple variable ex:

```
$this->session->user('username');
```

And the location is in the url:
    http://example.com/blog/post/

I can get the id using the `URL` helper so basicaly im having one variable with the username and an other variable with the location.

### The question

How can i send the location and the username with the form?
For example when someome clicks `Add comments` i want to pass the username and the location!

### Please note:

- I dont want to use a javascript request to make the request
- I need to use codeigniter's `form` library in order to render the forms
- Codeigniter is a PHP framework
- I could use a ready lib but i would love to write everything by my self

I hope you can understand. Please ask me if you have any question

Comment: Maybe hidden inputs, e.g : `form_hidden('username', $this->session->user('username'));`

Comment: what is the reason to send to CI information, that is already there???

Comment: You answer works perfectly! Post this as an answer so i can close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can use `form_hidden()`.

Example :

```
form_hidden('username', $this->session->userdata('username'));
```